# Show embedded social data in web page while using front end technology like react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to show embedded social data from twitter in reactjs which has script tags already to style and render twitter in place and hardcoded in database table with some contents? In monolithic sites, it works fine. In front end based on it does not work.

For example a content stored in db table as text:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum

<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">I just published “Making Sense of React Hooks” <a href=""></a></p>&mdash; Dan Abramov (@dan_abramov) <a href="https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1057319198626594816?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">October 30, 2018</a></blockquote>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
```

This script twitter wont load the default widget layout while using react with some paragraphs around it as hard coded content.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the script tag. You may add it to the index.html directly or use `componentDidMount` like so

```
componentDidMount () {
     const script = document.createElement("script");

     script.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
     script.async = true;

     document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

check this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkmvrdz0/) or you may want to check this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-widgets)

Comment: i.e. Every hard coded script tag need to be removed from the page and replace it via componentDidMount or add it in head. Will not make things complicated if its not just related to twitter. Then in such cases need to scan whole hard coded content remove it from there and add it in head. It will definitely make things worse an old monolithic website with lots of pages and lots of page views, need to shift to today's front end world, where everything was ok to copy paste and would work fine. It will lead to lot of backend processing.